# Fit or Compress Text in scrbook

Tags: koma-script, paper-size, fit

I would like to create a mass-market paperback size book using scrbook. The book in question is approximately 400 pages long at 6x9 dimensions. I would like the text to still be readable, but I'd like this version to have as few pages as possible. What packages are recommended, or what techniques/tricks can be used to best accomplish this?

I tried to search the site for answer, but I am caught in a captcha infinite loop. The first two or three times there were pictures, now I just check a box before I get yet another captcha. Hence this question.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,headings=small,BCOR=.25mm,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperheight=6.88in,paperwidth=4.25in, left=1cm]{geometry}
% will the binding correction affect the margins?
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[DIV=15]{typearea}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times NR Condensed}
\linespread{.9}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
blah blah
\end{document}
```

The following lines were deleted because LaTeX reported that they were causing conflicts with scrbook. It's odd the crop package caused a conflict.

```
%\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}   %added to save space
%\enlargethispage* %added to save space? didn’t work
%\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}
%\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop}
```

I tried reducing the font to 8 pts but it's really not readable. Are there any other suggestions, or packages that might help?

Comment: And what exactly is the question? Beside this: don't mix KOMA-tools to set the page (typearea, options like BCOR) and geometry. This is at best confusing.

Comment: Edited question. Is there a way to set a non-standard page size in Koma without using the geometry package?

Comment: I don't see an improvement. What is your concrete problem? And what do you mean by " I am caught in a captcha infinite loop"?

Comment: 1. I am seeking recommendations for limiting the number of pages in an scrbook project. This is different from a "it doesn't compile" or, "this package doesn't work" question. For example, using a .9 linespread is one such recommendation. Are there any others?  2. a.enter text in site search box. Hit return. Captcha pop-up appears. Attempt to click within captcha box. Additional picture pop-up appears requiring the selection of photographs similar to a given photograph. Click on matching photograph(s). Picture pop-up disappears. Click on box within captcha pop-up. Green arrow appears.

Comment: then...Captcha pop-up does not disappear. Close out captcha pop-up. Enter text in site search box. Repeat. Same Result. Repeat. Same result. This may not mathematically be an infinite loop but it appears to yield the same result.

Comment: Regarding your captcha problem: Ask on meta and/or flag a moderator. Your tex question is imho to broad. Your example (which didn't compile without error in my system) doesn't show enough content to be able to tell where you could save more space.

Comment: I am looking for generic recommendations. "openany" is another one. As to content,  I can hardly post the full 400 page tex file. The work around to the captcha problem was using another browser and creating a new identity because I have no idea what my Stackexchange password is. Maybe when I restart the browser it will be fixed--who knows? The reason why I mentioned this is because it is possible that someone had already asked this question and I wanted to avoid a RTFM response.

Comment: As mentioned, don't mix `typearea` and `geometry`. All the `typearea` stuff is done while/after loading the class, so any changes *afterwards* need a recalculation. Issue `recalctypearea`.

Answer (score 1):

There are times when *squeezing* isn't worth the trouble.

[image: michaelKaneScrbookSqueeze]

```
\documentclass[paper=4.25in:6.88in,pagesize=auto,fontsize=10pt,headings=small,BCOR=.25mm,openany,DIV=16]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\linespread{.9}
\raggedbottom
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```